# Unit Test data setup is hitting Apex CPU time limit

Tags: unit-test, test-setup, cpulimit

I have written a set of methods in a test class that can be called to create and insert relational test data. I am using `Test.StartTest()` and `Test.StopTest()` to keep the operations for the test in their own separate context, but the data setup itself is far exceeding the 10000ms time limit.

Is there any way to get the setup to not count toward any time limit? Alternatively, are there any obvious changes I can make that will reduce the execution time of either of these methods?

```
@isTest
public with sharing class GHTestServices {


    public static Map<String, List<SObject>> insertTestData_AccountsAndOpportunities(Integer numberOfAccounts, Integer numberOfOppsPerAccount) 
    {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) return NULL;

        //Create lists of values for Opp fields
        RecordType newBizRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND Name = 'New Business' LIMIT 1];
        RecordType renewalRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND Name = 'Renewal' LIMIT 1];
        List<ID> recordTypes = new List<ID>{newBizRecordType.id, renewalRecordType.id};

        List<Profile> aeProfiles = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name LIKE 'Account Executive%'];
        List<Profile> renewalsrepProfiles = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name LIKE 'Renewals%'];

        Set<Id> aeProfileIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> renewalsrepProfileIds = new Set<Id>();

        for(Profile p : aeProfiles) aeProfileIds.add(p.id);
        for(Profile p : renewalsrepProfiles) renewalsrepProfileIds.add(p.id);

        User activeAE = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE isActive = TRUE AND ProfileId IN :aeProfileIds LIMIT 1];
        User renewalsRep = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE isActive = TRUE AND ProfileId IN :renewalsrepProfileIds LIMIT 1];
        List<ID> oppOwners = new List<ID>{activeAE.id, renewalsRep.id};

        List<String> leadSources = new List<String>{'Inbound','Outbound'};
        List<String> marketingLeadSources = new List<String>{'Advertising','Directories','Direct Traffic','Earned Media','eBlasts','Greenhouse Events','List Purchase','Paid Content ','Paid Search','PR','Search','Social Media','Trade Show','Webinar','Lead Buy','Resources Section'};

        List<String> stages = new List<String>{'Discovery', 'Awaiting Renewal', 'Closed Won', 'Closed Won'};
        List<Date> closeDates = new List<Date>{system.today() + 30, system.today() + 30, system.today(), system.today()};

        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();

        Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String>();

        for(Integer i = 0; i < numberOfAccounts; i++)
        {
            String accountName = 'Account' + String.valueOf(Math.random()).left(20);
            accountNames.add(accountName);

            accounts.add(
                new Account(
                Name = accountName,
                Type = 'Pipeline',
                NumberOfEmployees = i*50,
                Industry = 'Technology',
                Handover_notes__c = '.',
                Billing_Contact_Name__c = 'name',
                Billing_Contact_Email__c = 'foo@bar.com'
                )   
            );
        }

        insert accounts;

        Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name, Type FROM Account WHERE Name IN :accountNames]);

        system.debug('Inserted test accounts:' + accountsMap.values());

        for(Account a : accountsMap.values())
        {
            String accountxname = a.name;
            Id accountxid = a.Id;

            for(Integer n = 0; n < numberOfOppsPerAccount; n++)
            {
                opps.add( 
                    new Opportunity(
                        AccountId = accountxid,
                        Name = accountxname + 'Deal',
                        RecordTypeID = recordTypes[math.mod(n,recordTypes.size())],
                        Amount = 10000,
                        CloseDate = closeDates[math.mod(n,closeDates.size())],
                        StageName = stages[math.mod(n,stages.size())],
                        OwnerId = oppOwners[math.mod(n,oppOwners.size())],
                        Initial_Appointment_Date__c = system.today() - 20,
                        Contract_Terms__c = 'None',
                        LeadSource = leadSources.get(math.mod(n,leadSources.size())),
                        Marketing_Lead_Source__c = marketingLeadSources.get(math.mod(n,marketingLeadSources.size())),
                        SBQQ__Contracted__c = FALSE
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        insert opps;
        List<Opportunity> insertedOpps = [SELECT Id, AccountId, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name, CloseDate, IsClosed FROM Opportunity];

        Map<String, List<SObject>> finalMap = new Map<String, List<SObject>>();
        finalMap.put('Account', accountsMap.values());
        finalMap.put('Opportunity',insertedOpps);

        return finalMap;
    }

    public static Map<String, List<SObject>> insertTestData_ContactsWithCampaignsAndCampaignMembers(List<Account> accountsToPopulate, Integer numberOfContactsPerAccount)
    {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) return NULL;

        system.debug('accountsToPopulate = ' + accountsToPopulate);

        List<Campaign> campaigns = new List<Campaign>();
        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers = new List<CampaignMember>();
        List<CampaignMemberStatus> cmStatuses = new List<CampaignMemberStatus>();

        //Pull custom setting value for CampaignMember statuses that qualify for OCR creation
        CustomGroupings__c cg = [SELECT Id, CampaignMemberStatusesForInfluence__c FROM CustomGroupings__c LIMIT 1];
        List<String> cmStatusesList = cg.CampaignMemberStatusesForInfluence__c.split(':');


        Set<String> contactNames = new Set<String>();

        campaigns.add(
            new Campaign(
                Name = 'TestCampaign',
                IsActive = TRUE,
                Type = 'Greenhouse Events'
            )
        );


        insert campaigns;

        List<Campaign> insertedCampaigns = [SELECT ID, Name, IsActive FROM Campaign WHERE Name = 'TestCampaign'];


        for(Campaign cp : insertedCampaigns)
        {
            Id campaignxid = cp.id;
            Integer sortindex = 4;

            for(String st : cmStatusesList)
            {
                CampaignMemberStatus cms = new CampaignMemberStatus(
                    CampaignId = campaignxid,
                    HasResponded = true,
                    Label = st,
                    SortOrder = sortindex
                );
                cmStatuses.add(cms);
                system.debug('Added CampaignMemberStatus to cmStatusesList:' + cms);
                sortindex ++;
            }
        }

        insert cmStatuses;

        List<CampaignMemberStatus> insertedCampaignMemberStatuses = [SELECT Id, Label FROM CampaignMemberStatus];

        List<String> testCMStatuses = new List<String>{'Sent'};
        for (CampaignMemberStatus cms : insertedCampaignMemberStatuses)
        {
            testCMStatuses.add(cms.Label);
        }

        Integer ind = 0;

        for (Account a : accountsToPopulate)
        {
            ID accountxid = a.id; 
            system.debug('iterating on accountsToPopulate; accountxid = ' + a.id);

            for(Integer i = 0;i<numberOfContactsPerAccount; i++)
            {
                String contactName = 'Contact' + String.valueOf(Math.random()).left(20);
                contactNames.add(contactName);

                contacts.add(
                    new Contact(
                        FirstName = 'Foo',
                        LastName = contactName,
                        AccountId = accountxid
                    )
                );
                system.debug('Added contact ' + String.valueOf(i) + ' for account # ' + String.valueOf(ind) + ' with ID ' + a.id);
            }
            ind++;
        }

        insert contacts;

        List<Contact> insertedContacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE LastName IN :contactNames];

        system.debug('inserted test contacts: ' + contacts);



        Integer index = 0;
        Integer statusIndex = 0;

        for(Contact c : insertedContacts)
        {
            if(math.mod(index,2) == 0) //Create a CampaignMember for every other contact
            {
                campaignMembers.add(
                    new CampaignMember(
                        CampaignId = insertedCampaigns[0].id,
                        ContactId = c.id,
                        Status = testCMStatuses[math.mod(statusIndex, testCMStatuses.size())]
                    )
                );

                system.debug('Created CM for contact index ' + String.valueOf(index) + '. Status = ' + testCMStatuses[math.mod(statusIndex, testCMStatuses.size())]);

                statusIndex++;
            }

            index++;
        }

        insert campaignMembers;

        List<CampaignMember> insertedCampaignMembers = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CampaignId, ContactId, Status FROM CampaignMember ORDER BY ContactId ASC];

        //For two out of every three CampaignMembers, we will change the createdDate to a long ago time (so that the contacts are eligible to have contact roles created)
        /*
        index = 0;
        Datetime longAgo = Datetime.now().addDays(-360);

        for(CampaignMember cm : campaignMembers)
        {
            if(math.mod(index, 3) > 1)
            {
                Test.setCreatedDate(cm.id, longAgo);
            }

            index++;
        }
        */

        Map<String, List<SObject>> finalMap = new Map<String, List<SObject>>();
        finalMap.put('Campaign',insertedCampaigns);
        finalMap.put('Contact',insertedContacts);
        finalMap.put('CampaignMember',insertedCampaignMembers);

        return finalMap;
    }

    public static Map<String, List<SObject>> insertTestData_LeadsWithCampaignsAndCampaignMembers(Integer numberofLeads)
    {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) return NULL;


        List<Campaign> campaigns = new List<Campaign>();
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
        List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers = new List<CampaignMember>();
        List<CampaignMemberStatus> cmStatuses = new List<CampaignMemberStatus>();

        //Pull custom setting value for CampaignMember statuses that qualify for OCR creation
        CustomGroupings__c cg = [SELECT Id, CampaignMemberStatusesForInfluence__c FROM CustomGroupings__c LIMIT 1];
        List<String> cmStatusesList = cg.CampaignMemberStatusesForInfluence__c.split(':');


        Set<String> leadNames = new Set<String>();

        campaigns.add(
            new Campaign(
                Name = 'TestCampaign',
                IsActive = TRUE,
                Type = 'Greenhouse Events'
            )
        );


        insert campaigns;

        List<Campaign> insertedCampaigns = [SELECT ID, Name, IsActive FROM Campaign WHERE Name = 'TestCampaign'];


        for(Campaign cp : insertedCampaigns)
        {
            Id campaignxid = cp.id;
            Integer sortindex = 4;

            for(String st : cmStatusesList)
            {
                CampaignMemberStatus cms = new CampaignMemberStatus(
                    CampaignId = campaignxid,
                    HasResponded = true,
                    Label = st,
                    SortOrder = sortindex
                );
                cmStatuses.add(cms);
                system.debug('Added CampaignMemberStatus to cmStatusesList:' + cms);
                sortindex ++;
            }
        }

        insert cmStatuses;

        List<CampaignMemberStatus> insertedCampaignMemberStatuses = [SELECT Id, Label FROM CampaignMemberStatus];

        List<String> testCMStatuses = new List<String>{'Sent'};
        for (CampaignMemberStatus cms : insertedCampaignMemberStatuses)
        {
            testCMStatuses.add(cms.Label);
        }


        for(Integer i = 0;i<numberOfLeads; i++)
        {
            String leadName = 'Lead' + String.valueOf(Math.random()).left(20);
            leadNames.add(leadName);

            leads.add(
                new Lead(
                    FirstName = 'Foo',
                    LastName = leadName,
                    Company = 'bar'
                )
            );
        }



        insert leads;

        List<Lead> insertedLeads = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE LastName IN :leadNames];

        Integer index = 0;
        Integer statusIndex = 0;

        for(Lead l : insertedLeads)
        {
            if(math.mod(index,2) == 0) //Create a CampaignMember for every other contact
            {
                campaignMembers.add(
                    new CampaignMember(
                        CampaignId = insertedCampaigns[0].id,
                        LeadId = l.id,
                        Status = testCMStatuses[math.mod(statusIndex, testCMStatuses.size())]
                    )
                );

                statusIndex++;
            }

            index++;
        }

        insert campaignMembers;

        List<CampaignMember> insertedCampaignMembers = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CampaignId, LeadId, Status FROM CampaignMember ORDER BY ContactId ASC];

        //For two out of every three CampaignMembers, we will change the createdDate to a long ago time (so that the contacts are eligible to have contact roles created)
        /*
        index = 0;
        Datetime longAgo = Datetime.now().addDays(-360);

        for(CampaignMember cm : campaignMembers)
        {
            if(math.mod(index, 3) > 1)
            {
                Test.setCreatedDate(cm.id, longAgo);
            }

            index++;
        }
        */

        Map<String, List<SObject>> finalMap = new Map<String, List<SObject>>();
        finalMap.put('Campaign',insertedCampaigns);
        finalMap.put('Lead',insertedLeads);
        finalMap.put('CampaignMember',insertedCampaignMembers);

        return finalMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: In case like that I always go from other side -- why do I need so much data to test something? Isnt there too much logic to test in single *unit* test? And in every case, I found a way how to rewrite test method, which fit all limits. But that require more than one generic test setup, and is individually applied

Comment: Profile your test code to see if one of your above methods isn't returning results and causing you to time out. Your sandbox may not have all the data you need to run this test class. You're querying much of it instead of creating it.

Comment: kurunve, the trigger utility that I'm testing has a quite complex scenario that it's built for, that in fact does require all of the related data in order to get good code coverage.

@ccrmprogdev, I've already profiled the code and it is returning results, it just takes a long time to the many different object inserts and queries.

I reduced the number records I'm requesting (in passed arguments) in the unit test that calls this setup method, and avoided the time limit issue. Now I'm not testing for worst case volume in my actual test scenario, but I guess it will suffice for now.

Comment: Some notes: (a) remove System.debug statements. They cost CPU time. (b) Use proper for loops instead of for-each loops. (c) Use describes instead of queries when possible. (d) avoid impossible logic, like "if(!system.isrunningtest()) return null;" These functions should only be called in test context.  (e) consider reusing smaller amounts of data. (f) try to limit your DML statements. (g) Consider a mechanism to disable triggers during testSetup. (h) You need to do profiling to figure out how to fix further problems.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thanks for your reply. Could you give a little more detail what you mean by (b), 'proper for loops'?  I will look into the rest of these suggestions as well, especially (g) - do you know of any documentation of a mechanism like that?

Comment: You can move some of the test data creation into a method flagged as @future to benefit from the higher limits